# Java Socket Paint Program

Tags: java, canvas, graphics

I made a paint program using sockets to transmit points from a canvas to all other users canvas.As i tested my program on different screens i came across a problem.On my laptop 1366x768 everything goes well but from a 1920x1080 screen laptop it goes discontinuous.If i draw something on the 1920x1080 screen laptop it displays smooth on my 1366x768 screen but when i draw something on the 1366x768 it happens what i say.I think the problem is not with the connection because i tried to put the server on both laptops(not simultaneously) and run one time from the big one and one time from the small one. It has to do with resolution? How i can fix this?

```
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    x=e.getX();
    y=e.getY();
}

public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
    x1=e.getX();
    y1=e.getY();
    gr=canvas.getGraphics();
    gr.drawLine(x, y, x1, y1);
    if(x!=x1||y!=y1)
    {
        try {
        PrintStream ps=new PrintStream(sc.getOutputStream());
        ps.println("!!##print"+" "+x+" "+" "+y+" "+x1+" "+y1);
    } catch (IOException e1) {

        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
    x=x1;
    y=y1;
}
```

here is the function which prints.Ignore the System.out because i used them to verify some things.

```
else if(mes.charAt(0)=='!'&&mes.charAt(1)=='!'&&mes.charAt(2)=='#'&&mes.charAt(3)=='#'&&
                        mes.charAt(4)=='p'&&mes.charAt(5)=='r'&&mes.charAt(6)=='i'&&mes.charAt(7)=='n'&&
                        mes.charAt(8)=='t'
                        )
                {
                    System.out.println("am intrat la desenat");
                    StringTokenizer tok=new StringTokenizer(mes);
                    String aii=tok.nextToken();
                    ArrayList<Integer> numere=new ArrayList<Integer>();
                    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
                    {   
                        numere.add(Integer.parseInt(tok.nextToken()));
                    }
                    Graphics gs=canvas.getGraphics();
                    gs.drawLine(numere.get(0), numere.get(1), numere.get(2), numere.get(3));
                }
```

EDIT:Another thing that happens is that the lower bound of the canvas on 1920x1080 doesn't appear.It seems like i have a small canvas on that resolution that the canvas from 1366x768

Comment: Could you provide some code where you send/recieve the points and how you draw it?

Comment: if you want something else say and i will put it

Comment: it isn't from resolution it is from networking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I think you should make some sort of transformation:

**1. make a standard resolution**
Let's say 1600*900 is the standard resolution, then you have to calculate the scale of the screens

**2. calculate a scale factor**

Standard res = 1600*900
User res = 1366x768
Scale = (1600/1366) and (900/768) both equal a number close to 1.171 so that's your scale "factor"

**3. now multiply the points**
The next thing you have to do is multiply the points, coordinates of the points with your factor from step 2. And then send this information

---

You can also do the opposite! 
Maybe it is better to make the standard resolution the resolution of the host who created the session

I hope this answer will give you an extra possibility, or that I gave you a new way of approach.

Comment: are you sure it is from resolution and not from delay in networking? i ask this because i can't figure out..

Comment: it isn't from resolution.i think it is from networking.when i connect 4 or more even on the same pc i get discontinuous lines.but thank you anyway for your advice